# why android System Image show as a broken link

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, intel

I have an old Intel CPU, UBUNTU 12, Eclipse IDE and Android SDK but my Emulator is too slow that i should wait about 30 to 45 min to load an android operating system so i decided to get an Intel image from [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/android-4-2-jelly-bean-x86-emulator-system-image) link and then i copy it in the sdk folder and open eclipse and went to android sdk maneger and i saw the link as :

> Broken x86 ATOM System Image

, what did i do wrong ? i try with another image but i get same message.

Comment: It may help to download the x86 system image directly from the Android SDK manager.

Comment: @AlexanderWeggerle this is not a good idea because the sdk maneger show it as **Broken link**

Answer (score 1):

What processor is on the host computer? The KVM Installation link below states some virtualization requirements on the processor that are not on every Intel processor.  You can run CPU-Z or similar utility to get the processor's arcane sku and then look up the processor's specs at ark.intl.com.

Intel mentions there is an extra step when using the emulator on Ubuntu -
" Note: Intel HAXM is for Windows and OS X operating systems only. For Linux hosts, Kernel-based Virtual Machine (KVM) can be used to accelerate emulation performance. For information on installing and configuring KVM on Ubuntu, refer to this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation "

Comment: "@Tim Duncan - Intel" My cpu model is :Intel(R) Pentium(R) D CPU 3.00GHz.is it supported?

Comment: @Shombol-shagol Yes if it is this 930 model, no if it is the 925 model - links below. (Intel® Pentium® D Processor 930 - http://ark.intel.com/products/27518/Intel-Pentium-D-Processor-930-4M-Cache-3_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB?q=Intel(R)%20Pentium(R)%20D) (Intel® Pentium® D Processor 925 http://ark.intel.com/products/27517/Intel-Pentium-D-Processor-925-4M-Cache-3_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB?q=Intel(R)%20Pentium(R)%20D)

Comment: something went wrong while answering your question, trying a 2nd time.
@Shombol-shagol Yes if it is this 930 model, no if it is the 925 model - links below. This command run on Ubuntu looks like an easier way to figure to find out: "kvm-ok" in a terminal session, response will be "INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used" if the part supports VT-x (Intel® Pentium® D Processor 930 - http://ark.intel.com/products/27518/Intel-Pentium-D-Processor-930-4M-Cache-3_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB?q=Intel(R)%20Pentium(R)%20D)